# Extjs store store cuts the last digits of a bigint values

Tags: extjs

I usesd Extjs 7.4. When I load data into an extjs store, I have the problem that the last digits are truncated for bigint values.
It doesn't matter if the model field type is int or number. Bigint values ​​are only displayed correctly if the type is string. I can't use the field as a string in the idProperty of the data model. Does somebody has any idea.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Adding models with BigInt values just work fine. Are you sure you adding record with BigInt construct? `store.add({field: BigInt(9223372036854776807)}`

Comment: To be more precise I meant `store.add({field: BigInt('9223372036854776807')}` as if you try to add a number which can't be represented with JS Number it wont work as expected:P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is a limit of javascript, not ExtJs. In fact if you try to create a new object with a bigint property you get some truncated number:

```
var record = {
    numericValue: 9223372036854776807,
    stringValue: "9223372036854775807"
};
console.log(record);
```

It prints:

```
{
    numericValue: 9223372036854776000,
    stringValue: "9223372036854775807"
}
```

---EDIT---

A solution could be to pass for the [convert](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-convert) config of the BigInt field defined in the store's model. Note that your property should be initially  read by the store as a string. Doing like this, the property will correctly store BigInt values:

```
Ext.define("MyStore",{
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",

    fields: [
        {
            name: "bigIntProp",
            convert: function (value) {
                return BigInt(value);
            }
        }
    ]
});

var store = new MyStore();

store.add({ bigIntProp: '9223372036854775807' });

// This correctly print the big int value now
console.log(store.getAt(0).get("bigIntProp"));
```

Comment: This is not BigInt, this is a Number property, no surprise it is truncated.

Comment: added in my answer a tested workaround by using the **convert** config on the field that needs to store BigInt values